# In JQuery, what does "mouse events" mean?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I've found out that `click()` [can be triggered by the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228742/jquery-mouses-click-is-launched-by-keyboard-navigation), even though it's a mouse event.

So what does [mouse events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) and [keyboard events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) mean?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery thing,  it's applicable to plain JS too, and is just the way Web pages are supposed to behave for accessibility purposes. Not everybody has a mouse or other pointing device, so you can simulate a mouse click on standard controls (buttons, checkboxes, etc) using the keyboard.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks. In my question I assumed these categories were JQuery things when they were JS. That's what happens when I'm learning both of them at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

They're just categories that the events are sorted into according to their device relationship, partly for documentation convenience.
While you may be able to trigger a click() using the keyboard, the event itself is categorised as a mouse related event, ie the action of physically clicking the mouse.  You are just emulating this behaviour when you trigger a click() manually

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events are events that have to do with actions of the mouse. These can be a click, double-click, mouse down, etc. Mouse events can be used in two different ways. The first way is to bind the click handler to the HTML element. The other is to call the click event within the jQuery code.

The jQuery keyboard events can be bound to any HTML element, but only the element that has focus will fire the event. Most of the time keyboard events will be bound to form elements (HTML input elements).